# 'asp_tags' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php

I upgrade the php version  5.6 to 7.2.
website link:
https://www.crazylisting.com/
error_log  show error:
PHP Fatal error:  Directive 'asp_tags' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `asp_tags` directive from your php.ini ?

Comment: I am puzzled why this question has been closed. It seems to me that people voting for this don't understand the problem. There are websites that after upgrading to php 7 suddenly get this 500 error and no, there are no more details. Their php programs that previously worked suddenly crash with this error.

Comment: For the uninitiated: Normally PHP puts its code between '<?php' and '?>'. However, there are alternative options and one was '<%' and '%>'. For some reason these were called asp tags. PHP has retired this option and since PHP 7 they cause the error message that is mentioned in the question. Unfortunately it is a very unhelpful message as it doesn't mention the offending file. As kode-kobold suggests above, even an entry in php.ini might cause the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading php is not as trivial as it sounds.
In php 7 these tags have been removed : `<% %>` and `<%= %>`
So basically you need to go through all your php files, open them in a text editor and find these and replace them like so :

`<%` should be replaced by `<?php`

`%>` should be replaced by `?>`

`<%=` should be replaced by `<?=`

When this is fixed there's high chance you'll face new errors :)

Comment: i check all the files and <% tag replaced <?php as above you discussed. But error still the same.

Comment: code-kobold just pointed right : Have you tried removing the asp_tags directive from your php.ini ?